# Rails, how to setup a foreign key to be auto assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

Given the following models:

```
User.rb

NetworkDepartment.rb (id, title,added_by)
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :added_by
```

I want to be able to create a network department and have the added_by assigned automatically. I have the following:

```
@network_department = current_user.network_departments.new(params[:network_department])
```

Why isn't current_user automatically setting added_by as the current_user.id ?

Thanks

Comment: is it automatically set if you use `user_id` instead of `added_by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `has_many :network_departments` in `User`? That should do it. Otherwise try `current_user.network_departments.build(params[:network_department])`